# After pressing a back button activities doesn't resumes to last activity

Tags: android, tabs

I am developing a one chat application. in which first screen has one button for continue and it redirects to home/main screen of window.In main screen i have five different tabs.

My main problem is that when i am on main screen and if i press back button,it redirects to home screen of device.but if clicked on launcher icon again application doesn't start from last state rather it starts from first screen.

If i press home button within any tab/screen then its working fine.clicking on launcher icon it redirects me to the last state/screen.

I want the same behaviour of home button on back button.

And i have noticed one thing this happens only on activity which has tab. on other activities even pressing a back button .application doesn't minimizes.

any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```